# subscript out of bounds of my own R Package

Tags: r, package, installation, devtools, roxygen2

New to creating my own R package to store my functions somewhere. I've had issues with this and have since deleted and unstalled it a few times to move it around and try to get it to work. It's currently sitting in a Microsoft OneDrive folder.

```
* installing *source* package 'MyPackage' ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in db[, "Version"] : subscript out of bounds
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'MyPackage'
* removing 'C:/Users/jsmith/Documents/R/R-3.4.1/library/MyPackage'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/jsmith/Documents/R/R-3.4.1/library/MyPackage'
```

The package information sits in my OneDrive folder as I mentioned, and I use add R scripts and update from there, using roxygen2 and devtools. Still new at this but having a hard time when I'm trying to update the whole package so that everything shows up. And if I have a remote machine that has access to the OneDrive folder, I'm still having an issue installing the package.

Hoping for your help!

Thanks

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's going on without some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to see how you actually set things up so we can debug the build process.

Comment: Yeah I usually provide reproducible examples but I'm not sure how to do that given that my package is local on my machine. What can I add to this to help? let me know and I'll gladly add it.

Comment: A `sessionInfo` might help. Also, can you install the package when it is stored in a simple folder like "c:/mypackages" (to check it is not a OneDrive problem)?

Answer (score 3):

Your DESCRIPTION file does not have a 'Version:' line.